# Redirecting to URLs without losing session object values

Tags: java, session, struts2, http-post, payment

I have got stuck after try a lot and now running out of deadlines
Developing the system for payment process.
Details: I am developing an Struts2 web application where after doing all initial validations from database in my system, I need to call an URL already shared by the Bank Partner and open the Bank url page on the same browser. In this page the user will do the payments. Now I have to expose an URL in my application, that Bank Partner will call and after this the same user will be able to see the result page in the same browser. So I have 2 task and I am stuck with both of them. For all this I am using Struts2 session to store all user data after successful login in my application.

What I have tried:
For calling Bank URL
// My application validation code successful, then
response.sendRedirect(Bank URL)

This losses the session, so all session data has lost.

And for the URL of my application for the result page is
ContextRootMyApp?TRXN_STATE=STEP4

When this is called I do not get any session object values.
sessionMap.get("TRXN_STATE") is null.

Please suggest me to proceed it in java.

```
Code:

    Web Logic.xml
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
        <wls:context-root>ContextRootMyApp</wls:context-root>

        <wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>
        </wls:container-descriptor>


        <session-descriptor>
            <url-rewriting-enabled>true</url-rewriting-enabled>
        </session-descriptor>

    Struts.xml
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default"
            namespace="/">
            <result-types>
                <result-type name="tiles"
                    class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
            </result-types>

            <default-action-ref name="pageNotFound" />



            <action name="navigateSystem" method="navigatePaySystem"
                class="com.action.PayConsultUserAction">
                <result name="success" type="redirectAction">pages/layout/consultUser.action</result>
                <result name="successForward" type="redirectAction">pages/layout/result.action</result>
                <result name="bankCalledPaySystem" type="redirectAction">pages/layout/bankInterfaceCallPay.action</result>          
            </action>

            <action name="bankInterfaceCallPay"
                class="com.action.PayConsultUserAction" method="bankCalledPaySystem">
            </action>
            <action name="result"
                class="com.action.PayConsultUserAction" method="getDataList1">
                <result name="success">/pages/pay/payName.jsp
                </result>
                <result name="error" type="tiles">consult</result>
                <result name="login">/pages/common/error.jsp
                </result>
            </action>
        </package>

    result.Action
    public void getDataList1() throws Exception {
                String url = bankurl;
                response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL(url));

        }catch (Exception e) {
                LoggerUtil.logFlowErrorLevel(log, e);
                errorDescripion = ConstantesApp.TECHNICAL_ERROR;
            }


        }

Bank is calling my application url
ContextRootMyApp?TRXN_STATE=STEP4
index.jsp is hit as welcome file
index.jsp
<%
    pageContext.forward("/navigateSystem.action");
%>

navigatePySystem.Action
public String navigatePaySystem() {
        String TRXN_STATE = (String) request.getParameter("TRXN_STATE");
            System.out.println("Reached Username"+sessionMap.get("Username"));
            return "";
    }
```

sop Results: Reached Username null
Session is lost

Comment: After reading more one thing that I understood is the approach is correct -- I have to use response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL(urlBank)) I am just missing something

Comment: you are missing the basics of the web application development, not just Java or struts. Actually I don't understand this question. If you have a code to show what is the problem, you'd better post it sooner.